# Sequelize Can't Add Value into Associated Object

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I am trying to to create an object with a child (association) that has the Id of the created object passed as a value to its property. I have tried to follow the documentation, but there is no value being passed with the SQL command.

Here is the SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO `organization` (`organization_id`,`organization_name`,`admin`,`updatedAt`,`createdAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'dfsadfadsfa','ter@test.cm','2016-01-08 02:23:04','2016-01-08 02:23:04');
```

No reference to `user`

Here is the route inserting into organization:

```
var express = require('express');
var appRoutes   = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var models = require('../models/db-index');

    appRoutes.route('/sign-up/organization')

        .get(function(req, res){
            models.User.find({
                where: {
                    user_id: req.user.email
                }, attributes: [ 'user_id', 'email'
                ]
            }).then(function(user){
                res.render('pages/sign-up-organization.hbs',{
                    user: req.user
                });
            })

        })

        .post(function(req, res, user){
            models.Organization.create({
                organizationName: req.body.organizationName,
                admin: req.body.admin,
                User: [{
                    organizationId: req.body.organizationId
                }]
            }, { include: [models.User] }).then(function(){
                console.log(user.user_id);
                res.redirect('/app');
            }).catch(function(error){
                res.send(error);
                console.log('Error at Post');
            })
        });
```

Here is the form submission:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <form action="/app/sign-up/organization" method="post">
                <p>{{user.email}}</p>
                <input type="hidden" name="admin" value="{{user.email}}">
                <input type="hidden" name="organizationId">
                <label for="sign-up-organization">Company/Organization Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sign-up-organization"  name="organizationName" value="" placeholder="Company/Organization">
                <br />
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

user.js model:

```
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'first_name'
    },
    lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'last_name'
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        isEmail: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    organizationId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'organization_id',
        allowNull: true
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
        generateHash: function(password) {
            return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
        },
    },
    instanceMethods: {
        validPassword: function(password) {
            return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
        },
    },


});
    return User;
}
```

organization.js model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var Organization = sequelize.define('organization', {
    organizationId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'organization_id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    organizationName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'organization_name'
    },
    admin: DataTypes.STRING,
    members: DataTypes.STRING
},{
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            Organization.hasMany(db.User, {foreignKey: 'user_id'});
        },
    },
});

    return Organization;
}
```

db-index.js: where the two are associated:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var path = require('path');
var config = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..','./config/config.js'));
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
    host:'localhost',
    port:'3306',
    dialect: 'mysql'
});

sequelize.authenticate().then(function(err) {
    if (!!err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err)
    } else {
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.')
    }
});

var db = {}

db.Organization = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/organization");

db.User = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/user");

db.Annotation = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/annotation");

db.Organization.associate(db);
db.Annotation.associate(db);

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

sequelize.sync();

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: As I see, have you tried <form action="/sign-up/organization" method="post"> in form submission ? It's not /app as it calls route file.

Comment: Hey, sorry I prepended /app to all routes being called within that file. This isn't an issue

Answer (score 0):

When I use Sequelize, I usually create a function that creates an instance of the sequelize model using the build method and I use the instance to save that instance to the database. With the returned instance you can do whatever you need.

```
var instance = models.Organization.build(data);
instance.save().then(function(savedOrgInstance){
    savedOrgInstance.createUser(userData).then(function(responseData){
    //do whatever you want with the callback })
})
```

I can't say I've seen a create statement as you've written it. What is the extra include statement for?

That should give that newly created user the association you're looking for.
You should checkout the setAssociaton, getAssociation, createAssociation methods in the docs. http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/

Comment: Hey Cameron, I was referring to this section in the documenation http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#creating-with-associations

Comment: At this point in the route, I have already created a user that is authorized, which is why I am able to access the user model properties, but for some reason my current create method isn't finding a organization_id value to pass to the user property. This is my assumption

Comment: Haha I haven't used that method before I don't think. That documentation is helpful though. Try doing Users: [{ ... : ...}] instead of User. The plural might be causing the error. For that method to work you may need a User.belongsTo(models.Organization......) in the User model also? Just two thoughts!

Comment: If your user is already created maybe a create statement including an already created user won't work? Seems like it would create both instances newly. Like I alluded to you could probably create the organization and then if you have the userid you could probably just call newOrgInstance.setUser(userData or instance). I think that's all I got unfortunately though!

Comment: It seems that you might be right about the having to create the instances at the same time or wait until the organization instance is created and then apply the value to the user model. I console.logged in the statement and it came back for undefined for `annotation` is that a good sign that this won't work together?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your Annotation model looks like/ it doesn't seem related to any query you posted here. I only see the associate method  being used on it. And what statement did you console log? And when you say "is this a good sign that this won't work together" do you mean that the way that you're writing your create statement currently? Or the way I suggested? Or the way you're associating models?